# How would you go about creating a heuristic function for a weighted graph?

Tags: graph-theory, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I have been looking into A star, and I understand that a heuristic function is what makes the algorithm much more efficient. However, I am trying to apply it to pathfinding on weighted graphs (without coordinates), and I am struggling to understand how one would create a heuristics function, particularly one based on calculating Euclidean distance. Could anyone explain how?

Comment: You need some kind of assumption about your graph to be able to write a heuristic. The basic heuristic for A* on a grid graph is based on the assumption "the shortest path probably goes approximately in the right geometric direction". If you have some kind of similar assumption for your graph, maybe you can come up with a heuristic. There is no "general" heuristic that would work for all graphs.

Comment: It is important to make sure your heuristic ia admissible.  An admissible heuristic is guaranteed never to overestimate cost to goal.  An admissible heuristic is optimistic one.